# css hover div flickering

Tags: html, css

Well, my HTML looks like this, when I hover over the image the two checkboxes with a black background should be visible.

```
<img class='itemImage'/>
 <div class='hoverDisplay'> 
  <div class="selctImgInptWrapper big">
    <input class="selctImgInpt" type="checkbox" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="selectWrapperImgRetouch big">
    <input class="selctImgRetouch" type="checkbox" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.hoverDisplay {
 height: 75px;
 font-size: 0.80rem;
 background-color: rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.3);
 background: rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.3);
 color: #ffffff;
 width: 95%;
 bottom: 8px;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 2px 5px;
 display: none; }

.hoverDisplay .selctImgInptWrapper {
 bottom: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 2px 5px;
}

.hoverDisplay .selectWrapperImgRetouch {
 bottom: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 2px 5px; }

.itemImage:hover ~ .hoverDisplay {
  display: block; }
```

It works fine when I hover on the image, the two checkboxes are visible, the problem starts when I hover on the checkboxes it starts to flicker
I am not able to figure out the false scenario here.

When I move my cursor to the black are which is `hoverDisplay` class it starts to flicker and I am not able to check any checkboxes. While moving my

[image]

Comment: Providing a fiddle or a snippet to easily reproduce this would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because you will loss the hover when you want to use the input as **you are no more hovering** the image but another element which is a sibling. To avoid this add another property to keep the `display:block` state:

```
.itemImage:hover ~ .hoverDisplay,
 .hoverDisplay:hover {
  display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you show the `checkboxes` when you hover over the image. And then when you hover the checkboxes ( because they are not inside the image ( they are impossible to be)  ) you hover out the image and css tries to hide them. But `checkboxes` are on top of the image, so the flickering happens.

You basically hover in and out the image in the same time.

One solution would be to wrap the `img` and `checkboxes` in a `div` and show the `checkboxes` when you hover over the `div` not just the `img`.

```css
.img-container {
  position:relative;
  width:350px;
}

.hoverDisplay {
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 0.80rem;
  background-color: rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.3);
  background: rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.3);
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 95%;
  bottom: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  display: none;
}

.hoverDisplay .selctImgInptWrapper {
  bottom: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.hoverDisplay .selectWrapperImgRetouch {
  bottom: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.img-container:hover .hoverDisplay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
<img class="itemImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
<div class='hoverDisplay'>
  <div class="selctImgInptWrapper big">
    <input class="selctImgInpt" type="checkbox" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="selectWrapperImgRetouch big">
    <input class="selctImgRetouch" type="checkbox" value="">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```